# My HP Pavilion 11 x360 keyboard is not working

Tags: keyboard

My HP Pavilion 11 x360 keyboard is not working.  It works fine in Windows 10 but I can only use the on screen keyboard in ubuntu.

Suggestions ?

I tried Ctlr+Alt+F3.  It took me out of the ubuntu desktop.  When I use Ctrl+Alt+F3 it takes me out of the ubuntu desktop to ubuntu 20.04.1 lts.  How do I get back to the ubuntu desktop ?

Comment: Others get it to [work](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Pavilion-x360-11-n010-touchpad-and-keyboard-not-working-on/td-p/7781905) in Ubuntu. Does it work during GRUB?

Comment: Yes, the keyboard works during GRUB.

Comment: I found the answer by archmule78 on Apr 19 -

So after a long and frustrating 3 day, I managed to get the Internal keyboard and touchpad working.

My solotuition is as follows:

Edit the grub defaults, my personal option is $sudo nano /etc/default/grub
edit the line containing "quiet splash" to read "quiet splash acpi=off"
Then run $sudo update-grub and sudo update-grub2
Reboot the system and it sould be working fine.